# Statistical text analysis, language modeling and information retrieval program - Rainbow

Tags: c, compiler-errors, classification, text-analysis, language-model

I am trying to use the library Rainbow (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mccallum/bow/src/bow-20020213.tar.gz) for a simple question however have not been able to compile the rainbow.c file.

Errors are

```
error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>

#include “bow/libbow.h”

         ^

./rainbow.c:23:10: fatal error: 'argp.h' file not found

#include <argp.h>

         ^

2 errors generated.
```

Is there any way to avoid that to generate a working compiled file.

This is after -

*

```
error: 'bow/libbow.h' file not found with <angled> include;
      use "quotes" instead
#include <bow/libbow.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         "bow/libbow.h"
In file included from ./rainbow.c:22:
./bow/libbow.h:40:10: fatal error: 'malloc.h' file not found
#include <malloc.h>             /* for malloc() and friends. */
         ^
```

*

Please kindly help by spending a few minutes if possible as I need that package for my chosen project question submission.

Comment: `“` and `”` are not the same as `"`. Only the latter works. `<malloc.h>` is not a standard header; use `<stdlib.h>` instead.

Comment: You seem to be trying to (write?/compile?) a C program, and the compiler is having trouble locating your #include'd libraries. What OS are you running, and what development tools do you have installed?

Comment: Have you edited the rainbow.c file? Looks like line 22 has the #include <bow/libbow.h> line.  You should read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: thanks all; the problem was solved by @melpomene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you edited the rainbow.c file? Looks like line 22 has the #include  line.  You should read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html and note that the angle-brackets search for files on the standard include path (which can be modified). Likely you need to do some installation.  Take a look for the README and make sure you have followed the install instructions.
I downloaded the bow package you linked, and looked inside. There is a rainbow.c (which you are apparently trying to compile. Read the included README file and follow the compilation/installation instructions included therein.